# Visual style of child form TitleBar different from main form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, titlebar

I'm adding several child forms to a main form. In XP it seems the titlebar is identical for parent/child, except close button is black, not red. But in Windows 7, as image shows, the child form titlebar is different from the main form.

[image]

How can this be fixed? 
Most important are the colors. But would like to understand the full limitations of both colors and style here.

The main form has

> IsMdiContainer = false

Adding sub forms by

```
var f = new ChildForm(); 
clientPanel.Controls.Add(f); 
f.TopLevel = false; 
f.BringToFront(); 
f.Show();
```

I don't think it's an option to use IsMdiContainer = true. I can't recall why as it's a long time ago, but think there was an issue with not being able to hide form borders, which I need.

Answer (score 4):

This is entirely normal.  When you set the Form.TopLevel property to false, the window stops behaving like a top-level window.  It turns into a child control, behavior is almost indistinguishable from a UserControl.  Except that your forgot to change the FormBorderStyle property, it still has the "I want a caption" and "I want a resizable border" style flags turned on.

Which Windows will render, as requested, but no longer using the visual style of a toplevel window.  Fallback is the classic look.

It isn't the only thing that goes wrong, the form also loses the ability to be activated.  Since child controls have no activation state, only a toplevel window does.  So it doesn't properly paint the caption anymore, it will always draw using the "not activated" colors, even if you set the focus to the form.  Another serious problem is that the drag-the-titlebar feature still works, allowing the user to move the window outside the parent window with no way to get back to it.

The only reasonable solution is to set the FormBorderStyle to None so these things don't go wrong.

If you meant to create your own MDI style windowing model but without the MDI ugliness then this is not a good solution.  Look at docking library, Weifenluo's free DockPanel Suite is very popular.

Comment: Thanks, good info! I'm aware of the behavior which is not a problem. I have my own custom solution for resize, snap edges, focus, save/load etc. Standard FormBorderStyle is None, so I'm just displaying titlebar for purpose of move, maximize/minimize and close. So I can live with the non-standard color rather than changing all this. If it's to understand the titlebar rendering can not be overridden..?